# Iterating over paginated list of objects in Django template, via JS

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

In a Django web app I maintain, users upload videos that others can playback. All videos are encoded as mp4s. In certain cases where browsers can't play this format (e.g. Firefox), I need to program an elegant fallback. I'm following the [example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Showing_fallback_content_when_no_source_could_be_decoded) - it covers all the bases nicely.

My Django template is backed by a paginated class-based `ListView`. It gets an `object_list` passed to it. I then iterate through this list and display the videos one by one. Each page has 10 video objects.

I.e., something like the following (simplified code):

```
    {% for vid in object_list %}

        <video width="500" height="350" controls autoplay>
        <source src="{{ vid.streaming_url }}" type='video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.8, samr"'>
            <a href="{{ vid.streaming_url }}">
                <img src="https://a2ua.com/404/404-005.jpg" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
             </a>
        <p>This browser can't run this video</p>
        </video>

    {% endfor %}
```

This is pretty straight forward. What's not straight forward (for me) is the accompanying JS, since I'm not well-versed in JS.

I'm trying the following:

```
<script>
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var v = videos[i];
    var sources = v.querySelectorAll('source'),
        lastsource = sources[sources.length-1];
    lastsource.addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML = v.innerHTML;
        v.parentNode.replaceChild(d, v);
    }, false);  
}
</script>
```

This is placed *inside* the forloop, right before `{% endfor %}`.The problem is it works correctly solely for the **last video** in *every page* under this setup. Note that placing it *outside* the forloop yields similar results.  I could be wrong, but I think it doesn't correctly take pagination into account. Can someone help me improve this?

Comment: You definitely should not be putting the script *inside* the loop. Move the script as close to the bottom of your page (before the closing `</body>` tag) as possible so that it is only called once, after all the videos have been loaded into the DOM. Does that still only work with the last video?

Comment: @solarissmoke: I put it right before {% endblock %} - it still seems to solely select the last video object on the page. And that too, not reliably (if I refresh the page, I see erratic behavior). I think my JS is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with variable scope in your Javascript. Because everything has global scope, it gets overwritten during each iteration of the loop and the only one that "sticks" is the last item in the loop.

Moving that logic into a function should resolve your problem:

```
<script>
// Define a function to apply the fallback logic to a single video element
var applyFallback = function(v){
    var sources = v.querySelectorAll('source'),
        lastsource = sources[sources.length-1];
    lastsource.addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML = v.innerHTML;
        v.parentNode.replaceChild(d, v);
    }, false);
};

var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    applyFallback(videos[i]);
}
</script>
```

This code should be **outside** the template loop, as close as possible to the closing `</body>` tag in your HTML.